# Comparing difference between values in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<string, float>` and want to select KeyValuePairs from that, where the difference between the float-values is smaller than a certain treshold.

This is the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, float> heights = new Dictionary<string, float> ();
```

sample entries:

```
"first", 61.456
"second", 80.567
"third", 62.456
"4", 59.988
"5", 90.34
"6", 82.123
```

i need those elements, with a small difference of their values, e.g. "first", "third" and "4" in a list or something similiar. the difference is a given float value, let's say 3.5

Is it possible to achieve that by Linq?

I tried to do this using loops, but it gets really messy somehow...

Comment: post your code for good response, and better understanding

Comment: The difference between what? The key and the value?

Comment: no, the difference between the values of each dictionary element. (Math.Abs(heights[key1] - heights[key2]))

Comment: errh it's best if you'd post a sample list and mark the values you want to be selected.

Comment: so the first value is your 'base' value and everything that differs by less or exactly 3.5 should be selected?

Comment: You're not specific enough, are you looking for one sequence or all sequences? Is the difference a static threshold or relative to the standard deviation? In your example why take 'first', 'third' and '4' rather then 'second' and '6'. There are many different algorithm that can answer your question as it is right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom method that look up for close values and accepts two parameters: dictionary that holds the values and float, that is used to hold the maximum lookup range :

```
    static Dictionary<string, float> FindRange(Dictionary<string, float> dict, float precision)
    {
        Dictionary<string, float> temp = new Dictionary<string, float>();
        List<int> counter = new int[dict.Count].ToList(); float[] values = dict.Values.ToArray();            

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)                            
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < values.Length; i2++)
                if (i2 != i && Math.Abs(values[i] - values[i2]) < precision) counter[i]++;            

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)    
           if (Math.Abs(values[i] - values[counter.IndexOf(counter.Max())]) < precision) 
               temp.Add(dict.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Value == values[i]).Key, values[i]);

        return temp;
    }
```

Example of usage :

```
static void Main()
{
        Dictionary<string, float> heights = new Dictionary<string, float>()
        {

            {"first", 61.456f},
            {"second", 80.567f},
            {"third", 62.456f},
            {"4", 59.988f},
            {"5", 90.34f},
            {"6", 82.123f}                
        };

        // returns max sequence of elements with difference less than 3f
        var newDict = FindRange(heights, 3f);

        foreach (var item in newDict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + "   "  + item.Value);
        }
}
```

Output :

```
first 61,456
third 62,456
4     59,988
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first sort the entries by value and then it will be easier to compare nearby entries.

```
var list = heights.ToList();
list.Sort((a,b) => {return a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value);});
bool first = true;
for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    if (Math.Abs(list[i-1].Value - list[i].Value) < threshold)
    {
        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
            Console.WriteLine(list[i-1]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    }
}
```

A working example on dotnetfiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OAeI6p).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,float>> matching = new List<KeyValuePair<string,float>>();

int i = 0;
var all = _dict.Select(kvp => kvp).ToList().OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value);
all.ForEach(kvp => {
    if(i < all.Count() - 1 && Math.Abs(all[i+1].Value - kvp.Value) < threshhold)
    {
         matching.Add(kvp);
         if(i == all.Count() - 1) matching.add(all[i+1]); // Need to manually add the final entry if it's a match
    }
    i++;
});
```